# How does one add a class to an HTML element after it has been loaded using AngularJS?

Tags: css, view, angularjs

I am working on a single page design portfolio site which should have the following page flow.

*NOTE: All `div`s have `transition: .3s ease;` applied to them.*

1. A visitor clicks a `nav` link (which will load a new view)
2. The new view loads into the main container `div`.

   *NOTE: It'll have a `margin-right: -100%;` applied to it so that it will load off of the page to the right hand side.*
3. The preexisting view gets `margin-left: -100%;` applied to it so
   that it slides left completely off the page view.

   At the same time the new view gets `margin-right: 0;` so that it
   slides into the page view from the right hand side.

How do I program the above process to take place in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options.

1. you can make a custom directive. Typically when you interact with the DOM you do so in the linking function of a directive. See the [directive guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
2. you could use a library like AngularUI which supports some basic animation ([Here is a demo](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/94b2ff9e92fdeb89a17b55b956d8693944fb229e/modules/showhide/demo/index.html)).
3. you could use Angular 1.1.x (unstable) version which includes support for animation and there are some examples to do what you want (Check out [$animate](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) service).
4. you can take a look at the source code (or just use) this angular module: https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav which does sliding transitions similar to what you want to achieve.

I personally think #1 is the best because it will help you learn directives. If this is a personal site, then perhaps #3 is the best option because the $animate service is exactly what you want and you can get away with using the unstable branch.

Comment: I'd like to learn directives so I'll go with #1. Thanks Jonathan.